# verb + としよう; verb (non volitional) + とする, what is it used for?

Tags: grammar

The sentence:

> とある田舎の村が魔獣の被害にあっているとして、偶然そこに**立ち寄ったとしよう**。お前ならどうする？

What is verb (non-volitional) + としよう used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「Verb + としよう」, in this context, is used to introduce a ***hypothetical*** situation.  It is roughly the equivalent of:

> "**Let's assume/suppose that ~~**."

As you seem to have noticed, this expression has nothing to do with 「Volitional Verb + とする」, which means "***to try to (verb)***".

> 「とある田舎{いなか}の村{むら}が魔獣{まじゅう}の被害{ひがい}にあっている**として**、偶然{ぐうぜん}そこに立{た}ち寄{よ}った**としよう**。 お前{まえ}ならどうする？」

thus means:

> "Let's assume that a certain village has fallen victim to a beast and then you accidentally dropped by there.  What would you do?"

Comment: and として is used as "and then"?

Comment: @personanongrata (と)する here means "to suppose/assume" ≂「(と)仮定する」. として is its te-form, so として literally means "suppose/assume and..." ≂「～と仮定して」. 「～～として、・・・としよう。」≂「～～と仮定して、・・・と仮定しよう。」 "Let's suppose that ~~ and (suppose) that ..."